# With the brain's propensity for homeostasis, how can some drugs be labelled addictive and others not?

Tags: psychopharmacology, addiction

The human body is always striving for [homeostasis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_homeostasis). One of the purposes of the brain is to maintain homeostasis, but also the brain needs to [maintain homeostasis](http://psychology.uchicago.edu/people/faculty/cacioppo/jtcreprints/cb07d.pdf) within itself.

**Ergo:**
Given the use of any drug, that acts of the brain, will cause a change in brain chemistry.

Why are some drugs are regarded [as addictive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substance_dependence) and others are not?

Comment: Generally those of a more dopamergic nature are more addictive as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a part answer to your question.

According to the article [Drug Facts: Understanding Drug Abuse and Addiction](http://www.drugabuse.gov/publications/drugfacts/understanding-drug-abuse-addiction) and [Drugs, Brains, and Behavior: The Science of Addiction](http://www.drugabuse.gov/publications/science-addiction/drug-abuse-addiction), addiction is a disease caused by some types of drugs.  Specifically, they rewire the brain to cause an overstimulus of the 'reward' centres and by imitating some of the pre-existing neurochemical messengers in the brain - essentially, 'tricking' the brain that homeostasis is maintained.

Related, the article ["Why does the rapid delivery of drugs to
the brain promote addiction?"](http://psy2.ucsd.edu/~mgorman/Samaha2005.pdf) (Samaha and Robinson, 2005) concluded that the rate of delivery is an important factor:

> that rapidly
>   delivered drugs might promote addiction by promoting
>   forms of neurobehavioural plasticity that contribute to
>   the compulsive pursuit of drugs.